# Pagination in Mongodb Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

is there any method to get the total count of document in the find operation along with the skip and limit in the query in MongoDB

```
 MongoClient.connect(Config.dbURI, function (err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
        console.log(uniqueId)
        db.collection(dbName).find({'uniqueId': uniqueId, 'isDeleted': false})
            .sort({modifiedDateISO: -1})
            .limit(parseInt(limit))
            .skip(parseInt(limit * page))
            .toArray((errFindChat, dataFindChat) => {

                           console.log(errFindChat, dataFindChat);

     });
});
```

Comment: If you are using mongoose, you can use "mongoose-paginate" https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate

Comment: I am using mongodb driver

Comment: No, there is no other way. Apply two queries .People will say there are approached we can do  I know this can be done by map-reduce also but the query would be 10x slower than using 2 query.

Answer (score 4):

I assume "uniqueId" is not the primary key!

```
MongoClient.connect(Config.dbURI, function (err, db) {
   if (!err) {
       console.log("We are connected");
       console.log(uniqueId)
       db.collection("collname").aggregate(
            [
              { "$match":  { "uniqueId": uniqueId, 'isDeleted': false} },
              { "$count":  "total" }, 
              { "$sort" :  {"modifiedDateISO": -1 },
              { "$limit":  parseInt(limit) },
              { "$skip" :  parseInt(limit * page) }  
            ]

        ).toArray((errFindChat, dataFindChat) => {
              console.log(errFindChat, dataFindChat);
        });
    }
});
```

[MongoDB Aggregate Count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)

Comment: name: 'MongoError',
      message: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: \'$count\'',
      ok: 0,
      errmsg: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: \'$count\'',
      code: 16436 }

Comment: I think because of version. You can try this instead of $count stage  `{ "$group":  {'_id': '$uniqueId' , 'total': { '$sum' : 1 }  }  }`

Comment: @edam 's solution is working, the page number should start from 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter with skip and limit and have the total count in only one request if you use .find..

If you want to retrieve documents, filter, and perform count operation in only one request you have to use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

```
db.coll.aggregate([
{$match: your find conditions},
{$group/project: your count operations, etc....},
{$skip: skip}, // pagination skip
{$limit: limit}, // pagination limit
...
]);
```

Comment: Hi, How can I get the total count of documents that match the conditions? since I need to display the page numbers in the front end

Comment: you have to separately query the db to get the count.

Comment: Is that any way to get the count along with the same query

Answer (score 0):

```js
var query   = {}; // Your condition
var options = {
    select:   'title date author',
    sort:     { date: -1 },
    populate: 'author',
    lean:     true,
    offset:   20, 
    limit:    10
};

Book.paginate(query, options).then(function(result) {
    // ... 
});
```

The mongoose-pagination is good